# return true or false if at least one record satisfies the condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store some conversations with this structure:

| sender | receiver | read |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Second | row | 1 |
| Second | row | 1 |
| Second | row | 0 |
| Second | row | 0 |

I have a query that returns the receiver and it's like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT receiver AS interlocutore FROM `conversazioni` WHERE sender='Second'
```

It returns `row` as expected.

What I'd like his to add a field where I can put true/false if there are unread messages (read=0).

So the expected result here is

| Interlocutore | read |
| --- | --- |
| row | 0 |

If there are no unread messages:

| sender | receiver | read |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Second | row | 1 |
| Second | row | 1 |
| Second | row | 1 |
| Second | row | 1 |

Then the expected result is

| Interlocutore | read |
| --- | --- |
| row | 1 |

So if there is at least one row in the table with read=0 then the query should return 0. If there are no records with read=0 then the query should return 1. How can I cable this logic into my query?

Comment: Looks like a simple MIN() and GROUP BY.

Comment: @UncleCarl read is a boolean, so 0 stands for false and 1 stands for true. They are not integers

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a true boolean type, they're just numbers. So you can use numeric functions like `MIN()` and `MAX()`.

Comment: You could also use `EXISTS()` with a correlated subquery.

Comment: @Barmar clear to me how to use MIN in this case. But how to use EXISTS? Can you give me an example?

Comment: If your data might contain different true/false values, use IF(MIN(`read`),1,0).

Comment: `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM conversazioni AS c1 WHERE c1.receiver = c.receiver AND read = 0) AS read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MIN to return 0 if any are unread or 1 if all are read:

```
SELECT receiver AS interlocutore, MIN(read) AS read
FROM `conversazioni`
WHERE sender='Second'
GROUP BY receiver
```

Note that MIN will ignore any rows where `read` is NULL.

In general, `SELECT DISTINCT columns` is interchangeable with `SELECT columns ... GROUP BY columns` except that the latter allows you to use aggregation functions.

A correlated subquery would be extreme overkill.